# Windows 10 system tray icon (Skype) keeps getting hidden

Tags: windows-10, icons, notification-area

I want to be able to always see the Skype icon in the system tray. I know of the setting in the task manager config (choose which icons should show, and I choose Skype to always show), but every few days this option resets, and I have to go in the options again to set it.

Does anyone know how can I get this config to be set permanently?

Comment: Try in folder `%appdata%/Microsoft` to rename `Skype for Desktop` and start Skype. The folder will recreated but you'll to restore all your Skype settings. Also ensure that Skype is fully updated.

Comment: Every time Skype gets updated, I have *some* evidence that windows thinks it is a new program.  It appears that this mechanism to show or hide applications is based on some sort of CRC/MD5/Hash of the binary itself and not it's name and path.

Comment: @harrymc Well I did that, let's see if it takes

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas This issue seems to only be with Skype for me. Even if Telegram updates very often, I always see it in the taskbar.

Comment: This happens on my newly installed Win 11 PRO too.

Comment: This appears to be a problem with the UWP (Windows Store) version of the Skype app and has been present for a few years.  Installing Skype for Desktop will get around this problem.